# How to click on a parent element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have following `HTML` element (hidden radio button)

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input class="type_radio" name="type" id="optionWIDGET" autocomplete="off" value="WIDGET" type="radio">
     WIDGET
</label>
```

Target element is a `<label>` and I can use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@class="btn btn-primary"]').click()
```

But the problem is that there are few more similar elements with attribute `class="btn btn-primary"`. So I want to make my `xpath` more specific by adding reference to child `<input>` element.

However,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@class="btn btn-primary"]/input[@id="optionWIDGET"]').click()
```

will click on `<input>`, but not on `<label>` element.

The question is: **how to click on parent element if I know the locator of child element**?

PS. Searching elementS by same class name and then clicking on element from list by its index is not acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/parent) axis. Try the following XPath.

```
'//input[@id="optionWIDGET"]/parent::label'
```

Comment: if my input didnt have an ID, but only had a name, could this work?

Comment: @roastbeeef - In the solution, instead of `id` use `name`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following `XPath` to click on the parent `label` of the `input`:

```
//input[@id="optionWIDGET"]/parent::label
```

So you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="optionWIDGET"]/parent::label').click()
```

Note that since the `id` attribute is unique on a webpage, you can select the desired `input` element without using `label[@class="btn btn-primary"]` at the beginning of your `XPath`.